# LeanFT - Report Configuration - UTF-8

Tags: leanft

I've found that the default template of leanFT HTML Report doesn't have the property charset="utf-8" in "meta" tag. Therefore, I cannot show any special character in the report such as "é", etc.
[leanFT HTML report without charset="utf-8"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2igAq.jpg)

At present, I have to put this property in the HTML report file manually, I don't like that anymore.

[Put the property into HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrso9.jpg)

[The result after put manually this property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoUZe.jpg)

Please tell me the way to config the leanFT HTML Report with charset="utf-8"

Comment: Can you give us more details?[I can't reproduce that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdQvk.png)

Comment: Hi Adelin,
I have found that the leanFT HTML Report does not have the property `charset="utf-8" `, therefore I cannot show the special character such as "é" on the report

Comment: Yes but do you really need the property? Because on my end I can show that special character in the report, as you can see in the screenshot from my comment above

Comment: Have you added something in your config file, Adelin?
I really need this property.

Comment: No, it's the default report configuration.

Comment: Oh! I really don't know why. Because the default template which I have currently, it doestn't have this property, so I must put this property manually into the report

Comment: I see you're using LeanFT 14.0. I tried this on 14.02. Maybe upgrade to latest version of LeanFT?

Comment: Thanks Adelin, I'll try

Comment: Curious.. did it work?

Comment: Thanks Adelin, but I cannot try because I am using trial version and my company doesn't accept using internet to download, so .... :( I really thank for your support.